# Python selenium select invisible drop-down when style =“display: none;"

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, invisible

I'm trying to select and click in an invisible dropdown menu using selenium webdriver.

HTML:

```
<div id = "ID_1" class="mb-outer-container" style="display: none;">
.....
     <select style="font-size:10px", onchange="dg_send('contractNonParticipationsDatagrid2080-form');>
        <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="20">20</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="30">30</option>
```

What I've been trying to do:

```
sel = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@style='font-size:10px']"))
sel.select_by_visible_text("20")
```

also tried to select by value:

```
sel.select_by_value("20")
```

Both lead to the same error:
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

It seems like I'm able to find the elemtent, but unable to select the and click the option in the dropdown

Comment: Maybe first, you can execute a script and set the style display to inline or something like that, and after that, try again your posted code

Comment: @ Williams I tried to do that already, however having troubles selecting the select element by style.

Comment: @AbiSaran can't provide the URL due to data protection policy. Log-In etc.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to display the dropdown to select the option.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//select[@style="font-size:10px"]').click()
```

This will click on the dropdown and show the options of the dropdown. Then you can click on the option.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//option[@value="20"]').click()
```

Also need to import this

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

The driver.find_element_by_xpath() is deprecated in newest version.

Comment: unfortunately I get the following error: Message: element not interactable. I think the problem is the display:none style...

Answer (score 0):

What I like to use (I use C#, hopefully I've translated well enough to python)
is the driver's javascript execute script functionality. Here's how I normally get around not interactable errors.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath"));
```

This will use javascript to intereact with the element instead of just trying to click on it. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for the input. this way I get no error, but unfortunately there is also nothing happening. Neither the dropdown menu is activated nor is the desired option clicked on

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=10, poll_frequency=2,
                                         ignored_exceptions=[NoSuchElementException,
                                         ElementNotVisibleException,
                                         ElementNotSelectableException])
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="contractNonParticipationsDatagrid2080-form"]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/span/select')))
sel = Select(element)
sel.select_by_index(1)
```

Thank you all!